How to escape characters for curl?
I'm writing a shell script that makes some curl requests.
This is the part causing me problems:
URL="http://127.0.0.1:${PORT}${LOCATION}"
echo $URL

sleep 10

RESULT=$(curl $URL)
echo $RESULT

The echo $URL command prints the following
http://127.0.0.1:5556/dex/auth/mock?client_id=client_test_id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8001%2Fauth%2Ftest%2Fcallback%2F&response_type=code&scope=openid+email&state=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJmYXN0YXBpLXVzZXJzOm9hdXRoLXN0YXRlIiwiZXhwIjoxNzIxNTAxMjc1fQ.BKf05SeFcL28MmblOOfqtOOsLJvOVap1QJpVWiMfhKA

If during the sleep I copy the url, open another shell and run
curl http://127.0.0.1:5556/dex/auth/mock?client_id=client_test_id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8001%2Fauth%2Ftest%2Fcallback%2F&response_type=code&scope=openid+email&state=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJmYXN0YXBpLXVzZXJzOm9hdXRoLXN0YXRlIiwiZXhwIjoxNzIxNTAxMjc1fQ.BKf05SeFcL28MmblOOfqtOOsLJvOVap1QJpVWiMfhKA

I get back the response I want, i.e.
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5556/dex/callback?state=ihxsnqzdligl5nh5aunftgg7b">Found</a>.

But if I run curl $URL inside the script, this is what I get
curl: (3) URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function

This is somehow related to characters escaping, but I wasn't able to find a solution.
I've tried with all possible quoting, and I've also tried to pass the string to Python's urllib.parse.quote_plus, without any success.
Why does curl behave differently from within a script than from within the shell?
Thank you in advance for any help you will be able to give me.

have you tried wget?

The very least would be to double quote the variable: $(curl "$URL")

@FPS Thanks for the suggestion. I have just tried and indeed wget does not give me any problems with the url. The problem, however, is that then wget automatically makes another call to the address that should return curl to me, and I don't want that call to be made

@ÁlvaroGonzález Trust me, I've tried A LOT of different quotings

curl and wget have several optional commands, maybe you find a clue in their manuals..

@FPS I converted my entire script to wget and it now works correctly and with far fewer lines. Thank you very much! I leave the post open because the question of how to pass that string to curl still stands

great, wget is recursive...
